# Your order “will be” ready for pickup … when?

Tags: apple-store

I received an email about my order from Apple, which states my order “will be” ready for pickup. No date is given.

[image: Pickup information for order XXXXXXX. Your order will be ready for pickup.]

Clicking through to the order page, the progress bar shows “Ready for Pickup” but the date above it is 3 days in the future.

[image: Thu Jul 27. Ready for Pickup. Your order is ready to be picked up.]

I am very confused whether the order is ready for pickup now, or will be ready for pickup on Thursday the 27th. Which is it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is an Apple Customer Support question.  Only Apple can answer questions regarding orders placed with them.

Comment: That said, the phrase “will be” is in the future tense.  It then gives you a date in the future.   The body of the text appears to be a canned message telling you to follow the pickup instructions (assuming on the date indicated).  If you’re not certain still, contact Apple for assistance.

Comment: Re: close vote, that is fair. I posted the question because I was surprised not to see this already attested online anywhere, so I thought I’d create the question I was hoping to find when I googled it.

Comment: Yes, the emails that I have received from Apple say "will be ready" when they "are ready".

Comment: I think I read it in the end as an unfinished sentence eg. 'will be ready for pickup next time you come into the store', as if that's something you do regularly and casually.. Me? I was straight on the bus into town.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the response from Apple reads in the future tense, it in fact indicates that the order **is** ready for pickup.

When I purchased my present MBP to be delivered to my local store, I was also confused about the wording, especially as the date I received the email was earlier than I'd originally been given and expected. However, off I went and it was ready for me.

If in doubt you could ring your pickup store to check.